# How to arrange data in Cassandra to get data in last in first out format

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa, cassandra-0.7

As we cannot sort data in Cassandra, I wanted to store data in such format that when I retrieve the data, I need to get data in ' last in first out format ' i.e if user enter comments when I retrieve data, I should first get very latest comment first and then older comments. I think it's something to do with comparator.

I have set following when configuring Cassandra:

```
assume posts comparator as utf8;
assume posts validator as utf8;
assume posts keys as utf8;
```

Please help - how should I create the column to arrange data in time format so that latest data is stored first?

Answer (score 2):

Columns in a row are always sorted, and you can iterate over the columns in a row in reverse order. Given these two facs we could model the situation you're describing by storing comments in a column family called "comments" where the row key is the post ID, and the columns represent the comments to the corresponding post. The columns are timestamts (either ISO formatted dates, UNIX timestamps or time UUIDs) and the values are the comment text bodies.

If you would now get the columns for a row and specify that you wanted them in reverse order you would get what you want. How to specify reverse order depends on your driver, but it's usually just an option to the command that retrieves a row, or a column slice.

Another way, which is more hackish, would be to take the UNIX timestamp of a post, and subtract it from a large integer, like 2^31, and use that as column key. That way columns would sort in reverse order by default. It's not pretty and the above method is more elegant.

If you worry about using timestamps because there could be collisions where two comments are posted at exactly the same time, use Cassandra's time UUID type.

Comment: Rather than use epoch - timestamp for the timestamp to get a reverse order, just use a reversed comparator: http://thelastpickle.com/2011/10/03/Reverse-Comparators/ .  It works easily with TimeUUIDType, as well.

Comment: Even better! Didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize your data such that the comparator is a timestamp.  You store your data in natural order and specify reverse order in your slice query.

Comment: I mean to use the term "timestamp" loosely.  As long as the natural order of your columns is sortable by time, the technique will work fine.  A sequence number would do just fine for this.

Comment: but how to tell cassandra to sort according to timestamp i mean on my machine its sorting in alphabetical order

Comment: One basic construct is columnfamily[key][name]=value, where value can be a serialized record, say a JSON or doc, maybe a CSV string.  If name is just a numeric ID, then that should work.  You could use a bigint and store milliseconds from epoch.  The column doesn't have to be a string, but if you want it to be, you could format a date string as `yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS`, and that would sort alphabetically in time order.